# How to use the age() function in postgresql inside a CREATE TABLE block

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, datetime, sql-function

I am trying to make a table called `Citizens` in postgresql using PGadmin and inside this table there is a column called `age`and I want this age to be calculated and put inside this column when I insert a new row.
My code is as shown below:

```
  create table citizens(
  first_name VARCHAR(40),
  last_name VARCHAR(45),
  birth_date DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),
  ssid BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  age INTERVAL AGE(TIMESTAMP birth_date),
  );
```

I get this error message when I run this query:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AGE"
LINE 6:   age INTERVAL AGE(TIMESTAMP birth_date),
                   ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 156
```

Comment: Do you expect that column `age` is correct i.e. re-calculated upon `select` in the future?

Comment: I do not know the answer to that

Comment: The way you are trying to do it the age will obviously be frozen when the record is created and not grow in the future. Is this the business logic? If not use a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) or a view. Further there is no `DATETIME` data type in PostgreSQL, use `timestamp` instead.

Comment: There is no need to store the age based on a timestamp (not "datetime"). You can easily calculate this when selecting from the table. You can put that into a view if you want.

Comment: 1) This is not a good idea. 2) The reason you got that  error was it should have been `age INTERVAL DEFAULT AGE(TIMESTAMP birth_date),`. Though doing that would lead to another error `ERROR:  cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression`.

Comment: 1. Ages change even when your static db records don't.   How do you expect to keep up?  2. Defaults cannot be calculated.  If you need it, calculate inside an Insert and an Update trigger.  3. Setting the default birthdate to now() is almost certainly wrong.  4. While you COULD declare the age as an interval, I would never tell someone I was 70 years, 9 months, 10 days, 12 hours, 12 minutes, and 30 seconds.  I'd make it an integer instead and tell people I'm 70 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is defining

```
age interval generated always as age(birth_date) virtual
```

Unfortunately Postgres does not support *generated ... virtual*. Your best option then is drop the column from table then create a view which derives that column. Something like:

```
 create view citizens_vw as 
   select *, age(birth_date) as age
     from citizens;
```

Or, even better, as the comment by @ChrisMaurer has it:

```
 create view citizens_vw as 
   select *, extract (year from age(birth_date))::integer as age
     from citizens;
```

A couple notes:

- Postgres does not have a datatype DATETIME. You can use TIMESTAMP or just DATE.
- NOW() seems like a poor choice for a default for `birth_date`. This
  is a case where defining it as `not null` and not having a default is
  a better option. Do not assume new `citizens` are just seconds or
  days old. Sometimes it is better too handle the exception rather
  that assuming incorrect data (which will likely never be updated).
  Well at least IMHO.